# clamd says socket in use by another process but I can't find one

Tags: linux, centos, anti-virus, socket, clamav

I'm running CentOS 5.3 (Final) and using rpmforge I installed clamd and prereqs ok. I started clamd and ran a freshclam all ok. But if I run "clamd PING" or clamd /path/to/file I get

> **ERROR: LOCAL: Socket file /var/run/clamav/clamd.sock is in use by another process**

Further detail below but I'm at a loss where to go from here now, any advice anyone?

```
[root@main ~]# clamd PING
ERROR: LOCAL: Socket file /var/run/clamav/clamd.sock is in use by another process

[root@main ~]# clamd -V
ClamAV 0.97.6/15499/Wed Oct 24 11:02:00 2012

[root@main ~]# ps -ef | grep clam
clamav    2744     1  0 14:28 ?        00:00:00 clamd
root      3932  3541  0 14:36 pts/0    00:00:00 grep clam


Installed Packages
Name       : clamd
Arch       : x86_64
Version    : 0.97.6
Release    : 1.el5.rf
Size       : 582 k
Repo       : installed
Summary    : The Clam AntiVirus Daemon
URL        : http://www.clamav.net/
License    : GPL
Description: The Clam AntiVirus Daemon
```

here's the config:

```
##
## Example config file for the Clam AV daemon
## Please read the clamd.conf(5) manual before editing this file.
##


# Comment or remove the line below.
#Example

# Uncomment this option to enable logging.
# LogFile must be writable for the user running daemon.
# A full path is required.
# Default: disabled
LogFile /var/log/clamav/clamd.log

# By default the log file is locked for writing - the lock protects against
# running clamd multiple times (if want to run another clamd, please
# copy the configuration file, change the LogFile variable, and run
# the daemon with --config-file option).
# This option disables log file locking.
# Default: no
#LogFileUnlock yes

# Maximum size of the log file.
# Value of 0 disables the limit.
# You may use 'M' or 'm' for megabytes (1M = 1m = 1048576 bytes)
# and 'K' or 'k' for kilobytes (1K = 1k = 1024 bytes). To specify the size
# in bytes just don't use modifiers.
# Default: 1M
LogFileMaxSize 0

# Log time with each message.
# Default: no
LogTime yes

# Also log clean files. Useful in debugging but drastically increases the
# log size.
# Default: no
#LogClean yes

# Use system logger (can work together with LogFile).
# Default: no
LogSyslog yes

# Specify the type of syslog messages - please refer to 'man syslog'
# for facility names.
# Default: LOG_LOCAL6
#LogFacility LOG_MAIL

# Enable verbose logging.
# Default: no
#LogVerbose yes

# Log additional information about the infected file, such as its
# size and hash, together with the virus name.
#ExtendedDetectionInfo yes

# This option allows you to save a process identifier of the listening
# daemon (main thread).
# Default: disabled
PidFile /var/run/clamav/clamd.pid

# Optional path to the global temporary directory.
# Default: system specific (usually /tmp or /var/tmp).
TemporaryDirectory /var/tmp

# Path to the database directory.
# Default: hardcoded (depends on installation options)
DatabaseDirectory /var/clamav

# Only load the official signatures published by the ClamAV project.
# Default: no
#OfficialDatabaseOnly no

# The daemon can work in local mode, network mode or both. 
# Due to security reasons we recommend the local mode.

# Path to a local socket file the daemon will listen on.
# Default: disabled (must be specified by a user)
LocalSocket /var/run/clamav/clamd.sock

# Sets the group ownership on the unix socket.
# Default: disabled (the primary group of the user running clamd)
#LocalSocketGroup virusgroup

# Sets the permissions on the unix socket to the specified mode.
# Default: disabled (socket is world accessible)
#LocalSocketMode 660

# Remove stale socket after unclean shutdown.
# Default: yes
FixStaleSocket yes

# TCP port address.
# Default: no
#TCPSocket 3310

# TCP address.
# By default we bind to INADDR_ANY, probably not wise.
# Enable the following to provide some degree of protection
# from the outside world.
# Default: no
#TCPAddr 127.0.0.1

# Maximum length the queue of pending connections may grow to.
# Default: 200
MaxConnectionQueueLength 30

# Clamd uses FTP-like protocol to receive data from remote clients.
# If you are using clamav-milter to balance load between remote clamd daemons
# on firewall servers you may need to tune the options below.

# Close the connection when the data size limit is exceeded.
# The value should match your MTA's limit for a maximum attachment size.
# Default: 25M
#StreamMaxLength 10M

# Limit port range.
# Default: 1024
#StreamMinPort 30000
# Default: 2048
#StreamMaxPort 32000

# Maximum number of threads running at the same time.
# Default: 10
MaxThreads 50

# Waiting for data from a client socket will timeout after this time (seconds).
# Default: 120
ReadTimeout 300

# This option specifies the time (in seconds) after which clamd should
# timeout if a client doesn't provide any initial command after connecting.
# Default: 5
#CommandReadTimeout 5

# This option specifies how long to wait (in miliseconds) if the send buffer is full.
# Keep this value low to prevent clamd hanging
#
# Default: 500
#SendBufTimeout 200

# Maximum number of queued items (including those being processed by MaxThreads threads)
# It is recommended to have this value at least twice MaxThreads if possible.
# WARNING: you shouldn't increase this too much to avoid running out  of file descriptors,
# the following condition should hold:
# MaxThreads*MaxRecursion + (MaxQueue - MaxThreads) + 6< RLIMIT_NOFILE (usual max is 1024)
#
# Default: 100
#MaxQueue 200

# Waiting for a new job will timeout after this time (seconds).
# Default: 30
#IdleTimeout 60

# Don't scan files and directories matching regex
# This directive can be used multiple times
# Default: scan all
#ExcludePath ^/proc/
#ExcludePath ^/sys/

# Maximum depth directories are scanned at.
# Default: 15
#MaxDirectoryRecursion 20

# Follow directory symlinks.
# Default: no
#FollowDirectorySymlinks yes

# Follow regular file symlinks.
# Default: no
#FollowFileSymlinks yes

# Scan files and directories on other filesystems.
# Default: yes
#CrossFilesystems yes

# Perform a database check.
# Default: 600 (10 min)
#SelfCheck 600

# Execute a command when virus is found. In the command string %v will
# be replaced with the virus name.
# Default: no
#VirusEvent /usr/local/bin/send_sms 123456789 "VIRUS ALERT: %v"

# Run as another user (clamd must be started by root for this option to work)
# Default: don't drop privileges
User clamav

# Initialize supplementary group access (clamd must be started by root).
# Default: no
AllowSupplementaryGroups yes

# Stop daemon when libclamav reports out of memory condition.
#ExitOnOOM yes

# Don't fork into background.
# Default: no
#Foreground yes

# Enable debug messages in libclamav.
# Default: no
#Debug yes

# Do not remove temporary files (for debug purposes).
# Default: no
#LeaveTemporaryFiles yes

# Detect Possibly Unwanted Applications.
# Default: no
#DetectPUA yes

# Exclude a specific PUA category. This directive can be used multiple times.
# See http://www.clamav.net/support/pua for the complete list of PUA
# categories.
# Default: Load all categories (if DetectPUA is activated)
#ExcludePUA NetTool
#ExcludePUA PWTool

# Only include a specific PUA category. This directive can be used multiple
# times.
# Default: Load all categories (if DetectPUA is activated)
#IncludePUA Spy
#IncludePUA Scanner
#IncludePUA RAT

# In some cases (eg. complex malware, exploits in graphic files, and others),
# ClamAV uses special algorithms to provide accurate detection. This option
# controls the algorithmic detection.
# Default: yes
#AlgorithmicDetection yes


##
## Executable files
##

# PE stands for Portable Executable - it's an executable file format used
# in all 32 and 64-bit versions of Windows operating systems. This option allows
# ClamAV to perform a deeper analysis of executable files and it's also
# required for decompression of popular executable packers such as UPX, FSG,
# and Petite. If you turn off this option, the original files will still be
# scanned, but without additional processing.
# Default: yes
ScanPE yes

# Executable and Linking Format is a standard format for UN*X executables.
# This option allows you to control the scanning of ELF files.
# If you turn off this option, the original files will still be scanned, but
# without additional processing.
# Default: yes
ScanELF yes

# With this option clamav will try to detect broken executables (both PE and
# ELF) and mark them as Broken.Executable.
# Default: no
DetectBrokenExecutables yes


##
## Documents
##

# This option enables scanning of OLE2 files, such as Microsoft Office
# documents and .msi files.
# If you turn off this option, the original files will still be scanned, but
# without additional processing.
# Default: yes
ScanOLE2 yes


# With this option enabled OLE2 files with VBA macros, which were not
# detected by signatures will be marked as "Heuristics.OLE2.ContainsMacros".
# Default: no
#OLE2BlockMacros no

# This option enables scanning within PDF files.
# If you turn off this option, the original files will still be scanned, but
# without decoding and additional processing.
# Default: yes
#ScanPDF yes


##
## Mail files
##

# Enable internal e-mail scanner.
# If you turn off this option, the original files will still be scanned, but
# without parsing individual messages/attachments.
# Default: yes
ScanMail yes

# Scan RFC1341 messages split over many emails.
# You will need to periodically clean up $TemporaryDirectory/clamav-partial directory.
# WARNING: This option may open your system to a DoS attack.
#      Never use it on loaded servers.
# Default: no
#ScanPartialMessages yes


# With this option enabled ClamAV will try to detect phishing attempts by using
# signatures.
# Default: yes
#PhishingSignatures yes

# Scan URLs found in mails for phishing attempts using heuristics.
# Default: yes
#PhishingScanURLs yes

# Always block SSL mismatches in URLs, even if the URL isn't in the database.
# This can lead to false positives.
#
# Default: no
#PhishingAlwaysBlockSSLMismatch no

# Always block cloaked URLs, even if URL isn't in database.
# This can lead to false positives.
#
# Default: no
#PhishingAlwaysBlockCloak no

# Allow heuristic match to take precedence.
# When enabled, if a heuristic scan (such as phishingScan) detects
# a possible virus/phish it will stop scan immediately. Recommended, saves CPU
# scan-time.
# When disabled, virus/phish detected by heuristic scans will be reported only at
# the end of a scan. If an archive contains both a heuristically detected
# virus/phish, and a real malware, the real malware will be reported
#
# Keep this disabled if you intend to handle "*.Heuristics.*" viruses 
# differently from "real" malware.
# If a non-heuristically-detected virus (signature-based) is found first, 
# the scan is interrupted immediately, regardless of this config option.
#
# Default: no
#HeuristicScanPrecedence yes

##
## Data Loss Prevention (DLP)
##

# Enable the DLP module
# Default: No
#StructuredDataDetection yes

# This option sets the lowest number of Credit Card numbers found in a file
# to generate a detect.
# Default: 3
#StructuredMinCreditCardCount 5

# This option sets the lowest number of Social Security Numbers found
# in a file to generate a detect.
# Default: 3
#StructuredMinSSNCount 5

# With this option enabled the DLP module will search for valid
# SSNs formatted as xxx-yy-zzzz
# Default: yes
#StructuredSSNFormatNormal yes

# With this option enabled the DLP module will search for valid
# SSNs formatted as xxxyyzzzz
# Default: no
#StructuredSSNFormatStripped yes


##
## HTML
##

# Perform HTML normalisation and decryption of MS Script Encoder code.
# Default: yes
# If you turn off this option, the original files will still be scanned, but
# without additional processing.
#ScanHTML yes


##
## Archives
##

# ClamAV can scan within archives and compressed files.
# If you turn off this option, the original files will still be scanned, but
# without unpacking and additional processing.
# Default: yes
ScanArchive yes

# Mark encrypted archives as viruses (Encrypted.Zip, Encrypted.RAR).
# Default: no
ArchiveBlockEncrypted no


##
## Limits
##

# The options below protect your system against Denial of Service attacks
# using archive bombs.

# This option sets the maximum amount of data to be scanned for each input file.
# Archives and other containers are recursively extracted and scanned up to this
# value.
# Value of 0 disables the limit
# Note: disabling this limit or setting it too high may result in severe damage
# to the system.
# Default: 100M
#MaxScanSize 150M

# Files larger than this limit won't be scanned. Affects the input file itself
# as well as files contained inside it (when the input file is an archive, a
# document or some other kind of container).
# Value of 0 disables the limit.
# Note: disabling this limit or setting it too high may result in severe damage
# to the system.
# Default: 25M
#MaxFileSize 30M

# Nested archives are scanned recursively, e.g. if a Zip archive contains a RAR
# file, all files within it will also be scanned. This options specifies how
# deeply the process should be continued.
# Note: setting this limit too high may result in severe damage to the system.
# Default: 16
#MaxRecursion 10

# Number of files to be scanned within an archive, a document, or any other
# container file.
# Value of 0 disables the limit.
# Note: disabling this limit or setting it too high may result in severe damage
# to the system.
# Default: 10000
#MaxFiles 15000


##
## Clamuko settings
##

# Enable Clamuko. Dazuko must be configured and running. Clamuko supports
# both Dazuko (/dev/dazuko) and DazukoFS (/dev/dazukofs.ctrl). DazukoFS
# is the preferred option. For more information please visit www.dazuko.org
# Default: no
#ClamukoScanOnAccess yes

# The number of scanner threads that will be started (DazukoFS only).
# Having multiple scanner threads allows Clamuko to serve multiple
# processes simultaneously. This is particularly beneficial on SMP machines.
# Default: 3
#ClamukoScannerCount 3

# Don't scan files larger than ClamukoMaxFileSize
# Value of 0 disables the limit.
# Default: 5M
#ClamukoMaxFileSize 10M

# Set access mask for Clamuko (Dazuko only).
# Default: no
#ClamukoScanOnOpen yes
#ClamukoScanOnClose yes
#ClamukoScanOnExec yes

# Set the include paths (all files inside them will be scanned). You can have
# multiple ClamukoIncludePath directives but each directory must be added
# in a seperate line. (Dazuko only)
# Default: disabled
#ClamukoIncludePath /home
#ClamukoIncludePath /students

# Set the exclude paths. All subdirectories are also excluded. (Dazuko only)
# Default: disabled
#ClamukoExcludePath /home/bofh

# With this option you can whitelist specific UIDs. Processes with these UIDs
# will be able to access all files.
# This option can be used multiple times (one per line).
# Default: disabled
#ClamukoExcludeUID 0

# With this option enabled ClamAV will load bytecode from the database. 
# It is highly recommended you keep this option on, otherwise you'll miss detections for many new viruses.
# Default: yes
#Bytecode yes

# Set bytecode security level.
# Possible values:
#       None - no security at all, meant for debugging. DO NOT USE THIS ON PRODUCTION SYSTEMS
#         This value is only available if clamav was built with --enable-debug!
#       TrustSigned - trust bytecode loaded from signed .c[lv]d files,
#                insert runtime safety checks for bytecode loaded from other sources
#       Paranoid - don't trust any bytecode, insert runtime checks for all
# Recommended: TrustSigned, because bytecode in .cvd files already has these checks
# Note that by default only signed bytecode is loaded, currently you can only
# load unsigned bytecode in --enable-debug mode.
#
# Default: TrustSigned
#BytecodeSecurity TrustSigned

# Set bytecode timeout in miliseconds.
# 
# Default: 5000
# BytecodeTimeout 1000
```

Comment: I read elsewhere a similar issue was caused by /tmp being chmod 660. I've checkedd /var/tmp and it's 777 with stickybit so should be ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you misunderstood the documentation. After `clamd` is started it accepts commands on the **socket** that it opens. What `clamd PING` does is try to start another instance of `clamd`, which did not work because there is one instance running already.

If you want to send commands to the `clamd` process, you should connect to the socket and send your commands. Like this:

```
$ echo PING | nc -U /var/run/clamav/clamd.sock
PONG
```

According to the documentation, you can also prefix the commands with "n" if you are writing them in your terminal, so `clamd` knows for sure that the end of the line is the end of the command.

```
$ echo nPING | nc -U /var/run/clamav/clamd.sock
PONG
```

Comment: correcting the command gave the same response as you "PONG" so it looks like clamd is ok afterall. Means my actual problem maybe in perl. I'm trying to use perls File::VirusScan using the Daemon::ClamAV::Clamd but it reports back: ",error,Did not get ping response from clamd" so I manually tested and, here we are. Thanks I'll have to post elsewhere for the perl problem

Comment: @chutz this command with : echo ping | netcat -u /var/run/clamav/clamd.sock delivers "could not resolve host" here - (with Manjaro - need then to change firewall to deny instead to reject ?) ...

Comment: @dschinn1001, that is a capital `-U` ("Use UNIX domain socket"), and what you tried is a lowercase `-u` ("UDP mode"). Also, keep in mind that there are many, many versions of netcat and not all of them support the `-U` option.

Comment: the clamd socket may be named clamd.ctl instead of clamd.sock (it is named this way under LinuxMint)